# trying to print URL using css print

Tags: css, html

In my code below, I am working with CSS print feature. So, when I use the following code, I can see a URL next to the `KRON4` in two scenarios:

1) When I view the page in my browser window and 
2) When I click print button on my browser.

I am trying to print the URL only in the case of scenario 2 mentioned above. That is, when I click the print button on my browser window, I should see the URL next to KRON 4, and for that I replaced the content of `<style>` tag in the code below with the following `media query`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print body {
        a[href^="http://"]:after {
            content: " (" attr(href) ")";
            color: blue;
            font-size: small;
        }
    }
</style>
```

I don't see the URL getting printed after using the above style content.

Please consider the following code without media query  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Print Media and Mobile Devices</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style type="text/css">
         a[href^="http://"]:after{
         content: " (" attr(href) ")";
         color: blue;
         font-size: small;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>
         <a href="http://kron4.com/">KRON 4</a> 
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css is almost complete and should be working if you add

```
display: inline-block;
```

so, you css should be

```
@media print body {

a[href^="http://"]:after{
content: " (" attr(href) ")";
color: blue;
display: inline-block;
font-size: small;
        }

        }
</style>
```

link to working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ganhnuu/3/). This will work in all browers.

Answer (score 1):

My idea here would be a bit different approach as seen here in this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ganhnuu/)

The thing is that I hide the link and make it visible only when printing happens. I tested it in the JS Fiddle (Mozilla Firefox Print Preview) and worked, but please make sure you test it in other browsers as well. Oh and also you can make some float:left or other styling to the .hide class in order to position the link.

So the trick is something like this:

```
.hide {
  display:none;
}

@media print {
.hide {
    display:inline-block;
  }
}
```

Hope it helped,

Andrew